# Adding Interest/debt to a bank framework python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python3, and I have made a framework for a "bank" including deposits, withdrawals, and payments. Of course, the bank is heavily centralized, and I am the only one who is capable of making these deposits/withdrawals. I am not searching for encryption or security but I am searching for a way to add interest to account balances and add interest to debt, in addition to having a finite amount of money in the economy (i.e. I cannot just deposit money in accounts infinitely). To be specific, I want weekly interest on balances, and I want any debt to the bank to be paid with interest. I am at a loss here.
This is the code:

main.py:

```
import s as s
import b as b
import d as d
import l as l


bList2 = b.bList
dList2 = d.dList
sList2 = s.sList
log2 = l.log

index2 = 0
class test:

  def __init__(self):
    global index2
    global bList2
    global dList2
    global sList2
    self.ID = index2
    index2 += 1
    thing = self.ID in s.sList
    if thing == True:
      self.balance = bList2[self.ID]
      self.debt = dList2[self.ID]

    else:
      self.balance = 5000
      self.debt = 0
      bList2.append(self.balance)
      dList2.append(self.debt)
      thing2 = open("b.py", 'w')
      thing2.write("bList = " + str(bList2))
      thing2.close()
      thing3 = open("d.py", 'w')
      thing3.write("dList = " + str(dList2))
      thing3.close()
      sList2 = s.sList
      sList2.append(self.ID)
      thing4 = open("s.py", 'w')
      thing4.write("sList = " + str(sList2))
      thing4.close()

  def withdraw(self, amount):

    global bList2
    global log2

    if amount > self.balance or self.balance < 0:

      bal3 = (self.balance - amount)      
      bal2 = ((self.balance - amount) * -1)
      thing5 = str(input("Are you sure you would like to withdraw $" + str(amount) + " from your account? You will be $" + str(bal2) + " in debt. (y/n)")).lower()
      if thing5 == "y":
        thing6 = str(input("Are you sure? (y/n)")).lower()
        if thing6 == "y":
          self.balance = bal3
          bList2[self.ID] = self.balance
          thingy8 = open("b.py", 'w')
          thingy8.write("bList = " + str(bList2))
          thingy8.close()
          log2.append("Account ID " + str(self.ID) + " withdrew $" + str(amount) + "and now has a current balance of $" + str(bal3))
          thing9 = open("l.py", 'w')
          thing9.write("log = " + str(log2))
          thing9.close()
    else:

      bal4 = (self.balance - amount)
      thing10 = str(input("Are you sure you would like to withdraw $" + str(amount) + " from your account? You will have $" + str(bal4) + " remaining. (y/n)")).lower()
      if thing10 == "y":

        bList2[self.ID] = bal4
        thing11 = open("b.py", 'w')
        thing11.write("bList = " + str(bList2))
        thing11.close()
        log2.append("Account ID " + str(self.ID) + " withdrew $" + str(amount) + " and now has a current balance of $" + str(bal4))
        thing12 = open("l.py", 'w')
        thing12.write("log = " + str(log2))
        thing12.close()
        self.balance = bal4

  def deposit(self, amount):

    global bList2
    global log2

    if amount <= 0:
      print ("Please provide an amount that is above $0.00")
    else:
      bal5 = (self.balance + amount)
      thing14 = str(input("Are you sure you would like to deposit $" + str(amount) + " in your account? Your current balance is $" + str(self.balance) + " and your deposit will raise it to $" + str(bal5) + " (y/n)")).lower()
      if thing14 == "y":
        self.balance = bal5
        bList2[self.ID] = self.balance
        thing15 = open("b.py", 'w')
        thing15.write("bList = " + str(bList2))
        thing15.close()
        log2.append("Account ID " + str(self.ID) + " deposited $" + str(amount) + " and now has a current balance of $" + str(self.balance))
        thing16 = open("l.py", 'w')
        thing16.write("log = " + str(log2))
        thing16.close()

  def pay(self, amount, receiver):

    global bList2
    global log2

    thingy2 = receiver.ID in s.sList

    if thingy2 == True:

      if amount > self.balance or self.balance <= 0:
        print ("not enough funds")
      elif amount <= 0:
        print ("please provide a number that is greater than 0")
      else:
        thingy3 = (self.balance - amount)
        thingy4 = str(input("Are you sure you would like to pay account ID " + str(receiver.ID) + " a sum of $" + str(amount) + "? You will have $" + str(thingy3) + " remaining. (y/n)")).lower()
        if thingy4 == "y":
          thingy5 = (receiver.balance + amount)
          receiver.balance = thingy5
          self.balance = thingy3
          bList2[receiver.ID] = thingy5
          bList2[self.ID] = thingy3
          thingy5 = open("b.py", 'w')
          thingy5.write("bList = " + str(bList2))
          thingy5.close()
          log2.append("Account ID " + str(self.ID) + " paid account ID " + str(receiver.ID) + " $" + str(amount) + ". Account ID " + str(self.ID) + " currently has a balance of $" + str(self.balance) + ", and account ID " + str(receiver.ID) + " has a balance of $" + str(receiver.balance))
          thingy6 = open("l.py", 'w')
          thingy6.write("log = " + str(log2))
          thingy6.close()
    else:
      print ("receiver ID does not exist.")


def printLog():

  thingy = (len(log2))
  for x in range(thingy):
    print(log2[x])
    print ("")

a = test() #account ID 0
b = test() #account ID 1
c = test() #account ID 2
d = test() #account ID 3
```

b.py:

```
bList = [5000, 5000, 5000, 5000]
```

d.py:

```
dList = [0, 0, 0 ,0]
```

l.py:

```
log = []
```

s.py:

```
sList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So basically, b.py is a list of all the balances,
d.py is a list of all/any debt anybody has from over withdrawal, l.py is just a log so that any deposits, withdrawals, or transactions are recorded, and s.py is a list of every account's ID to determine whether or not an account should go through a setup process of multiple default values (5000 for balance, 0 for debt).

To rephrase, what I want to do is add a few things to my code without changing it too much that will do the following:

1) Create compound interest on people's deposits which is added weekly
2) Have some sort of place withdrawn money goes to that is bound to each account (this obviously gets no interest)
3) Create compound interest on people's debts and have each payment made weekly
4) Have some sort of way for the bank to make profit allowing for the economy to grow when many people make accounts
5) Have the log mention the time of a withdrawal/deposit/transaction

That is a little much, but I am stumped as to where to even begin for all of these things.

Comment: This is probably too broad. You should focus on how to add one feature at a time, which is a much smaller problem that you may be able to solve yourself—or, if not, that you can write a specific and easily-answerable question for.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is create a `Bank` object that stores all the accounts in a list or dict, instead of keeping them in a bunch of separate global variables. Then maybe a `Simulation` object that for now just has a single `Bank` instance. Then your first question becomes "How do I advance the time for my simulation, and make the bank calculate interest on deposits and debts over time?" Which you can do by, e.g., advancing the time in discrete one-week steps and just adding a method to the bank to calculate a week's worth of interest, which you call each step.

Comment: From there, you can add all kinds of things—put the `Person` objects who own the account in the Simulation and have them do banking activity every week, or add an abstracted `Economy` object, etc. Meanwhile, other things, like adding logging (see the `logging` module in the docs, and its Tutorial and Cookbook), can be done orthogonally to expanding the simulation design, which gives you at least two paths to go back and forth between so whenever you feel stuck on one, you can progress on the other.

Comment: Have you looked at how double-entry accounting works? E.g. interest accrual doesn't "create" money, it transfers money between the bank's profit/loss to some accrual account; cash withdrawal doesn't "destroy" money, it transfers money from the account "I(the bank) have this much cash" to the account "I(the bank) owe this much money to Bob", etc. There's a lot of literature, textbooks and other learning material about it.

Comment: One last thing: since simulation are one of the two original paradigm "things OO is good for", going back to Simula (hence the name) and Smalltalk, there must be lots of good tutorials on OO design for simulations. I don't know where to find one, but you should definitely look around.